# Contact Me vs Contact Us on a Business Directory Listing

Tags: lists, business-application, contact-us, directory

For a Business Directory Listing page, we are using cards UI for each listing. Here's the content structure:

[image]

Currently the Details link opens a modal with the Business details while the Contact Me opens the user's email client. (I also suggested that it is best that both links have the same behavior but I haven't backed this up yet.)

My main concern is the wording 'Contact Me'. I have a feeling that 'Contact Us' sounds more appropriate for a business listing but I can't find any articles to back it up. Are there any resources that list which of these two is best to use in this case? If none, recommendations from the experts on which is best to use would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contact Us` can seem more professional because it indicates that there are multiple people involved.
`Contact Me` on the other hand is more personal (makes sense if its about a single person).

These thoughts are appropiate if it is your own site, for a listing of other people's businesses I would just go with `Contact`.

Anyways this is more an issue for https://english.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends upon to whom the customer/user is contacting to.
If he is contacting a person or group which is not pre-determined we should use Contact Us.

> This organization is an expert and can really help you with so and so. `Contact Us` by clicking here

If the person/group who would be replying is already determined, we have following options.

If the page, where such a link is to be displayed is written in first person e.g.

> I am Ms. Expert, and I can help you with so and so. `Contact Me` by
>   clicking here

If it is written in third person

> Meet Ms. Expert, she is extremely knowledgeable and can help you. `Contact her` by clicking here.

Or

> We are a great organization `Contact our sales head, Mr. Sales Head` by clicking here.

Answer (score 0):

I think if businesses are personal and if you can use **user face picture** as advertise pic,it's be more friendly to use "contact me". but otherwise , use "contact us".